# Probleme with the filter of state with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I am trying to add bill into the billItems state using redux Toolkit and I don't
want to have multiple same bill with the same Id in the billItems. Each bill is like
{billId: 5, billName: "string"}. I made many attempts but nothing work as I want

**First Attempt**

```
export const billSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bill",
  initialState: {
    billItems: [],
  },
  reducers: (state, action) => {
    const arr = [...state.billItems];
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      state.billItems = [...arr, action.payload];
    } else {
      const filteredArr = arr.filter(
        (item) => item.productId !== action.payload.productId
      );
      state.billItems = [...filteredArr, action.payload];
    }
  },
});
```

With this attempt when I make may dispatch it just change the previous bill and
replace by the new one which is not the needed result

**Second attempt**
I decide to keep lastBill in the initialSate, take all billItems state with multiple same bill
and go to filter it in the selector using lastBill property.
in the selector like this

```
export const bSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bill",
  initialState: {
    lastBill: {},
    billItems: [],
  },
  reducers: (state, action) => {
    state.billItems = [...state.billItems, action.payload]
});
```

And my selector is like

```
const billItems = useSelector(state => {
  const arr = state.billItems
  const lastBill = state.lastBill
  const lastBill_Id = state.lastBill.lastBillId
  if(arr.length === 0){
    return [...arr, lastBill]
  }else{
    // I filter to obtain a new array whithout any instance of the lastBill
    const filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item.billId !== lastBill_Id)
    // I push now the lastBill to be sure that it is unique in the array and return it
    return [...filteredArr, lastBill]
  }
} )
```

But with this attempt when i populated the store with the same bill, the store
save it then I have many same bills in the state billItems which is not the needed result

There something that I don't undersatnd. please i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many research, I have an issue for this. the problem was the reference of objects in Javascripts. I make change in the billSlice like this.

```
 [add_to_billItems_action.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      let arr = state.billItems;
      if (arr.length === 0) {
// I make a copy of arr and modify billItems. At that time arr and billItems have the same payload
        
        state.billItems = [...arr, action.payload];
       
        arr = state.billItems;
      } else {
        let filteredArr = arr.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
        state.billItems = [...filteredArr, action.payload];
      }
```